# facebook send api - sending message "without" recepient id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to send a message (using Facebook API) to user that just gave us some (which?) permissions but haven't sent any message to us?

Answer (score 0):

No you must have the recipient set.

- recipient is required.
- message or sender_action must be set.
- notification_type is optional.

[Here's the documentation.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference)

Comment: I'd rather think that maybe exist some permission that allows the page to send message to user without first interaction from user side (e.g. permission that gives recipient id)

Comment: There is subscription messaging, but it has very limited use cases. And the user still needs to connect to your bot initially - you can not send stuff to people who never used your bot at all.